# Helm Conditional template for Resource request

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, optional-values

I want to implement a conditional template for Deployment resources through helm which can be enabled or disabled as per the environment. Something like the below which in not working. Or can we achieve the same through a different method.

```
resources:
     enabled: true 
  requests:
     cpu: 100m
     memory: 128Mi
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add condition in the deployment template

```
{{- if .Values.resources_limit.enabled }}
    resources:
    {{- toYaml .Values.resources_limit.resources | nindent 12 }}
{{- end }}
```

and the value file should be like this

```
resources_limit:
  enabled: true
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 128Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 128Mi
```

to disable, for example, `develop-values.yaml`

```
resources_limit:
  enabled: false
```

Comment: getting below error when set it to true

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[0].resources): unknown field "enabled" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ResourceRequirements

Comment: got it, updated and it should wokr now

Comment: Thanks for the help Its working now, but kindly rectify the indentation resource will not come under resources_limit

Comment: the value block? its working for me so if you want to suggest something please feel free to update the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can also check directly on **resource** value without adding the **If** **condition** or introducing a new variable in `values.yaml`

```
resources:
  {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
```

**values.yaml** if values added in `values.yaml` they will get applied to the template else will get ignored.

```
resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 128Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 128Mi
```

**Disable it**

```
resources: {}
```

For ref : https://opensource.com/article/20/5/helm-charts